# Magento 2: Observer constructor not working

Tags: magento2, event-observer, dependency-injection

I am creating an observer for an event in Magento 2 and followed all the steps in the documents I should follow. The observer is called after I registered it in the events.xml file. However, it doesn't work when I set a dependency in the constructor.

So, strangely enough, this code doesn't work:

```
<?php
namespace MyName\MyModule\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

class MyObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ){
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        //Observer execution code...
        echo 'This is a test';
    }
}
?>
```

And when I leave the constructor empty, everything works fine:

```
public function __construct(){

}
```

This is the case for every dependency I try to load. Can anyone figure out what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: It should work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure that you are operating in **developer mode**, otherwise you would need to recompile (`bin/magento setup:di:compile`) after every changed dependency.

#### Check current mode:

```
bin/magento deploy:mode:show
```

#### Set developer mode:

```
bin/magento deploy:mode:developer
```

If you already are in developer mode, there might be some generated files left over from the previous mode, or because you ran `setup:di:compile` in developer mode (which you should not). You can delete them with:

```
rm -r var/generation/* var/di/*
```

Answer (score 0):

As Fabian Schmengler said make sure you are working in Development mode.

When you create a class in module some code is generated in `var/generation` directory, so If you change the definition of the class in you module `app/code/<vendor>/<module>` the generated code in `var/generation`  is now invalid, which result in exceptions/error.

So, If you have added new parameters to the constructor you have to do following things

1. Delete `var/generation` directory
2. reindex `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`
3. clear cache `php bin/magento cache:clean`

Know more

> http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/php/php_clear-dirs.html
>   http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/code-generation.html

Comment: (2) and (3) are not helping, as the Magento indexer and cache have nothing to do with dependency injection and generated code. If you are in production mode, you need `setup:di:compile`, but during development you should *not* use production mode.

Comment: ya, that is a mistake on my side I was saying Development mode, don't know how I end up writing production instead of development mode. updated my answer

Comment: after doing step-1, you have to re-index and clear cache, so that if there is any cache it will get deleted. if there is cache for the page then the code will not be regenerated in `var/generation`, so it is very important to deleted cache.

Comment: But the index is irrelevant.

Comment: @LM_Fielding yes, the indexing is irrelevant, I know that now..